# commutator to entropy in an uncertainty relationship?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, entropy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

***Question:*** *Does there exist a commutator to entropy in an uncertainty relationship?*

Similar Energy and time for instance.

Comment: Hmm... Entropy of a system is proportional to the ln of the number of states that system can take on.  But what linear operator can give you that?

Comment: Entropy is a macroscopic quantity, defined in terms of the density matrix: $S = -\text{Tr}(\rho \ln \rho)$. It doesn't have an associated Hermitian operator. Think of it as a kind of expectation value.

Comment: @joshphysics - Of course! Well spotted! Unfortunately stack exchange doesn't let you edit comments after five minutes, so my mistake remains frozen as a relic for all eternity.

Comment: @poorsod: Sign mistake fixed.

Comment: @poorsod : $\rho$ is an hermitian operator, so $ln \rho$ and $\rho ~ ln \rho$ are hermitian operators too.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi : see also  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43175/uncertainty-principle-for-information

Comment: @Trimok you put your finger exactly on my painful problem. It is a Hermitian. I know the other link from the PSE but that makes an excurse too far. I tried to distinguish the two problems Entropy (Hermetian Matrix) and partition function that comes up when maximizing entropy, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70489/ Your help is very appreciated

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi : Even if $\ln \rho$ is hermitian, it does not mean that it is a "standard" observable. The density matrix, in the Heisenberg representation, could be understood, from my point of view, as "initial conditions". So, a physical observable $X$ has nothing to do with "initial conditions"; only the mean value of the operator needs both the operator and the density matrix .$ln \rho$, depending on $\rho$, cannot be a true observable.

Comment: @Trimok, al-Hwarizmi: even if $\rho \ln \rho$ is Hermitian (I'm not certain that it is, actually), it is _not_ the operator for entropy. $S$ is a scalar quantity - it's the trace over $\rho \ln \rho$. As Trimok points out, not every Hermitian operator corresponds to an observable.

Comment: @poorsod : If an operator $X$ is hermitian, every operator $f(X)$ is hermitian. $S$ could be considered as the mean value of the operator $Y=ln \rho$, in the state defined by the density matrix $\rho$ - $S = Tr(\rho Y) = Tr(\rho ln \rho)$. But the fact that $ln \rho$ depends on $\rho$, is the indication that $ln \rho$ could not be considered as an ordinary observable.

Comment: @Trimok apropos observability. Lets have the same exercise for the macroscopic $S_{max}=\lambda \sum_i \psi_i + \sum_p \lambda_p \sum_i \psi_i f_i^{(p)}$, where $\lambda_p$ some Lagrane multipliers, $\lambda=\ln Z$ with $Z$ a partition function and $f_i^{(p)}$; what would be the commutator to $S_{max}$?